# calculate mean using numpy ndarray

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

The text file look like:

```
david weight_2005 50
david weight_2012 60
david height_2005 150
david height_2012 160
mark weight_2005 90
mark weight_2012 85
mark height_2005 160
mark height_2012 170
```

How to calculate mean of weight and height for david and mark as follows:

```
david>> mean(weight_2005 and weight_2012), mean (height_2005 and height_2012)
mark>> mean(weight_2005 and weight_2012), mean (height_2005 and height_2012)
```

my incomplete code is:

```
 import numpy as np
 import csv
 with open ('data.txt','r') as infile:
   contents = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ')
   c1,c2,c3 = zip(*contents)
   data = np.array(c3,dtype=float)
```

Then how to apply np.mean??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read your data directly in a numpy array with:

```
data = np.recfromcsv("data.txt", delimiter=" ", names=['name', 'type', 'value'])
```

then you can find appropriate indices with np.where :

```
indices = np.where((data.name == 'david') * data.type.startswith('height'))
```

and perform the mean on thoses indices :

```
np.mean(data.value[indices])
```

Comment: it would be better if you could explain the meaning of *  in your code @Nicolas Barbey

Comment: There is a TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not numpy.str_. How to correct for it?@Nicolas Barbey

Comment: * is just multiplication of boolean arrays.

Comment: I do not understand the TypeError. I tested on python 2.7.3. What is your version of python ?

Comment: i am using python 3.2 and numpy 1.8 @Nicolas Barbey

Comment: the type error produced in python 3 and numpy 1.8 has been solved by @DSM under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944408/getting-indices-in-numpy

Answer (score 5):

The `mean` function is for computing the average of an array of numbers.  You will need to come up with a way to select the values of `c3` by applying a condition to `c2`.

What would probably suit your needs better would be splitting up the data into a hierarchical structure, I prefer using dictionaries.  Something like

```py
data = {}
with open('data.txt') as f:
    contents = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
for (name, attribute, value) in contents:
    data[name] = data.get(name, {})  # Default value is a new dict
    attr_name, attr_year = attribute.split('_')
    attr_year = int(attr_year)
    data[name][attr_name] = data[name].get(attr_name, {})
    data[name][attr_name][attr_year] = value
```

Now `data` will look like

```
{
    "david": {
        "weight": {
            2005: 50,
            2012: 60
        },
        "height": {
            2005: 150,
            2012: 160
        }
    },
    "mark": {
        "weight": {
            2005, 90,
            2012, 85
        },
        "height": {
            2005: 160,
            2012: 170
        }
    }
}
```

Then what you can do is

```
david_avg_weight = np.mean(data['david']['weight'].values())
mark_avg_height = np.mean([v for k, v in data['mark']['height'].iteritems() if 2008 < k])
```

Here I'm still using `np.mean`, but only calling it on a normal Python list.

Comment: thanks for your efforts, upvoted! but i am looking for more shorter way to do it mainly using numpy @bheklilr

Comment: @nils NumPy isn't going to make this code any shorter.  Even in your example, your code is all parsing the file.  Mine just parses the file into a more useful data structure that can then have NumPy functions applied to it.  All you want NumPy for is calculating the average, but because you want to be able to do it by conditions, you need to get your data into a form that is more easily manipulated.  Pandas might be a good library for doing this for you, but I personally don't see why 9 lines of code is too long.

Answer (score 4):

I'll make this community wiki, because it's more "here's how I think you should do it instead" than "here's the answer to the question you asked".   For something like this I'd probably use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) instead of `numpy`, as its grouping tools are much better.  It'll also be useful to compare with `numpy`-based approaches.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep="[ _]", header=None, 
                 names=["name", "property", "year", "value"])
means = df.groupby(["name", "property"])["value"].mean()
```

.. and, er, that's it.

---

First, read in the data into a `DataFrame`, letting either whitespace or `_` separate columns:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep="[ _]", header=None, 
                 names=["name", "property", "year", "value"])
>>> df
    name property  year  value
0  david   weight  2005     50
1  david   weight  2012     60
2  david   height  2005    150
3  david   height  2012    160
4   mark   weight  2005     90
5   mark   weight  2012     85
6   mark   height  2005    160
7   mark   height  2012    170
```

Then group by `name` and `property`, take the `value` column, and compute the mean:

```
>>> means = df.groupby(["name", "property"])["value"].mean()
>>> means
name   property
david  height      155.0
       weight       55.0
mark   height      165.0
       weight       87.5
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

---

.. okay, the `sep="[ _]"` trick is a little too cute for real code, though it works well enough here.  In practice I'd use a whitespace separator, read in the second column as `property_year` and then do

```
df["property"], df["year"] = zip(*df["property_year"].str.split("_"))
del df["property_year"]
```

to allow underscores in other columns.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is always in the format provided.  Then you could do this using array slicing:

```
(data[:-1:2] + data[1::2]) / 2
```

Results in:

```
[  55.   155.    87.5  165. ]
```