# Variable/unknown length string/unicode dtype in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Is it possible to somehow load an array with a text field of unknown field length?

I figured out how to pass `dtype` to get string into it. However, with out specifying length i just get `U0`. Type which seems not to be able to hold any data. E.g:

```
data = io.StringIO("test data lololol\ntest2 d4t4 ololol")
>>> ar = numpy.loadtxt(data, dtype=[("1",str), ("2",'S'), ("3",'S')])
>>> ar
array([('', b'', b''), ('', b'', b'')], 
      dtype=[('1', '<U0'), ('2', '|S0'), ('3', '|S0')])
```

When I change to mode with specified size I get input:

```
>>> data.seek(0)
0
>>> numpy.loadtxt(data, dtype=[("1",(str,30)), ("2",(str,30)), ("3",('S',30))])
array([("b'test'", "b'data'", b'lololol'),
       ("b'test2'", "b'd4t4'", b'ololol')], 
      dtype=[('1', '<U30'), ('2', '<U30'), ('3', '|S30')])
```

I'd be fine with either `S` or `U` probably. The field in my case is supposed to be used to hold set of textual flags. Something like linux environmental variables. Thus, preallocating large space just in case seems like a big waste. Especially when number of rows goes into millions.

I do understand, or have ideas, where such design can come from. Like constructing a `struct` like object that holds whole row in continuous memory block. However, I thought maybe there could a way to make it keep like a pointer in case of strings.

Is it possible?

Comment: Not the task numpy is suited for. You can for example encode your strings (i.e. manually construct pointers) with say `hash` function, and store theme elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getting indices in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944408/getting-indices-in-numpy)
uses `np.recfromtxt`, which can generate the `dtype` automatically.  Effectively it calls `np.genfromtxt` with a `dtype=None`.

Data like:

```
david weight_2005 50
david weight_2012 60
david height_2005 150
david height_2012 160
```

produces a:

```
array([('david', 'weight_2005', 50), ('david', 'weight_2012', 60),
       ('david', 'height_2005', 150), ('david', 'height_2012', 160),...], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S5'), ('f1', 'S11'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

The code in `genfromtxt` for determining `dtype` looks complex.  My guess it adjusts the `Snn` to accommodate the longest string that it encounters in that field.

One way to customize the `dtype` is to assign `names` in `getnfromtxt`, and recast the values after with `astype`.

```
x=np.genfromtxt('stack19944408.txt',dtype=None,names=['one','two','thr'])
x.astype(dtype=[('one','S10'),('two','S10'),('thr','f')])
#array([('david', 'weight_200', 50.0), ('david', 'weight_201', 60.0),
#       ...
#      dtype=[('one', 'S10'), ('two', 'S10'), ('thr', '<f4')])
```

Comment: I see there is no simple solution. Your solution kinda works, but it's like I was afraid, it needs to preallocate space regardless of the actual data. My problem is that the field can be from around `10` to `100` characters long, this goes for 10^6 to 10^8 rows. That's why I don't like it. I accepted your solution because for smaller data sets it's probably ok and works automatically, which I like. I personally coded flags into binary and provided `str <=> uint` dictionary mappings to decode them later. This way I had some extra work, but save a lot of space.

Comment: So you are worried that if `genfromtxt` chooses `S100` to accommodate your longest record field, that there will be a lot of blanks in the other records?  I think that has to be the case if the strings are stored in the array itself (with constant record size).  The alternative is `object` `dtype`, with the strings stored as regular Python strings (and just pointers in the array).