# NumPy dtype issues in genfromtxt(), reads string in as bytestring

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I want to read in a standard-ascii csv file into numpy, which consists of floats and strings.

E.g.,

```
ZINC00043096,C.3,C1,-0.1540,methyl
ZINC00043096,C.3,C2,0.0638,methylene
ZINC00043096,C.3,C4,0.0669,methylene
ZINC00090377,C.3,C7,0.2070,methylene
...
```

Whatever I tried, the resulting array would look like

E.g.,

```
all_data = np.genfromtxt(csv_file, dtype=None, delimiter=',')


[(b'ZINC00043096', b'C.3', b'C1', -0.154, b'methyl')
 (b'ZINC00043096', b'C.3', b'C2', 0.0638, b'methylene')
 (b'ZINC00043096', b'C.3', b'C4', 0.0669, b'methylene')
```

However, I want to save a step for the byte-string conversion and was wondering how I can read in the string columns as regular string directly.

I tried several things from the numpy.genfromtxt() documentation, e.g., `dtype='S,S,S,f,S'` or `dtype='a25,a25,a25,f,a25'`, but nothing really helped here.

I am afraid, but I think I just don't understand how the dtype conversion really works...Would be nice if you can give me some hint here!

Thanks

Comment: why do you hate `np.bytes_` so much ?

Comment: Aside: in my experience when people want to put both text and numbers into a numpy array they'd usually be better off working with a [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) `DataFrame`.

Comment: @zhangxaochen - If I recall correctly (can't test on python3, at the moment), having the columns as bytes won't allow you to use numpy's vectorized string operations.  I could be misremembering, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python2.7

```
array([('ZINC00043096', 'C.3', 'C1', -0.154, 'methyl'),
       ('ZINC00043096', 'C.3', 'C2', 0.0638, 'methylene'),
       ('ZINC00043096', 'C.3', 'C4', 0.0669, 'methylene'),
       ('ZINC00090377', 'C.3', 'C7', 0.207, 'methylene')], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S12'), ('f1', 'S3'), ('f2', 'S2'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', 'S9')])
```

in Python3

```
array([(b'ZINC00043096', b'C.3', b'C1', -0.154, b'methyl'),
       (b'ZINC00043096', b'C.3', b'C2', 0.0638, b'methylene'),
       (b'ZINC00043096', b'C.3', b'C4', 0.0669, b'methylene'),
       (b'ZINC00090377', b'C.3', b'C7', 0.207, b'methylene')], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S12'), ('f1', 'S3'), ('f2', 'S2'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', 'S9')])
```

The 'regular' strings in Python3 are unicode.  But your text file has byte strings.  `all_data` is the same in both cases (136 bytes), but Python3's way of displaying a byte string is `b'C.3'`, not just 'C.3'.

What kinds of operations do you plan on doing with these strings? `'ZIN' in all_data['f0'][1]` works with the 2.7 version, but in 3 you have to use `b'ZIN' in all_data['f0'][1]`.

[Variable/unknown length string/unicode dtype in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646275/variable-unknown-length-string-unicode-dtype-in-numpy)
reminds me that you can specify a unicode string type in the `dtype`.  However this becomes more complicated if you don't know the lengths of the strings beforehand.

```
alttype = np.dtype([('f0', 'U12'), ('f1', 'U3'), ('f2', 'U2'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', 'U9')])
all_data_u = np.genfromtxt(csv_file, dtype=alttype, delimiter=',')
```

producing

```
array([('ZINC00043096', 'C.3', 'C1', -0.154, 'methyl'),
       ('ZINC00043096', 'C.3', 'C2', 0.0638, 'methylene'),
       ('ZINC00043096', 'C.3', 'C4', 0.0669, 'methylene'),
       ('ZINC00090377', 'C.3', 'C7', 0.207, 'methylene')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<U12'), ('f1', '<U3'), ('f2', '<U2'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<U9')])
```

In Python2.7 `all_data_u` displays as

```
(u'ZINC00043096', u'C.3', u'C1', -0.154, u'methyl')
```

`all_data_u` is 448 bytes, because `numpy` allocates 4 bytes for each unicode character.  Each `U4` item is 16 bytes long.

---

Changes in v 1.14: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#encoding-argument-for-text-io-functions

Comment: This requires you to know the dtype a priori, while the python2.7 solution allowed you to specify `dtype=None`. Is there any similar behavior that will cast to unicode in python3?

Comment: `dtype=None` creates bytestrings in both py2 and 3.  `similar behavior` can interpreted in two ways - as bytestring, or as the default str.

Comment: @kadrlica Version 1.14 has given us more flexibility, with an `encoding` parameter.  See recent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723311/stringio-example-does-not-work

Answer (score 8):

In python 3.6,

```
all_data = np.genfromtxt('csv_file.csv', delimiter=',', dtype='unicode')
```

works just fine.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Answered my problem.....

Answer (score 4):

```
np.genfromtxt(csv_file, dtype='|S12', delimiter=',')
```

Or you could select the columns that you know are strings using the `usecols` parameter:

```
np.genfromtxt(csv_file, dtype=None, delimiter=',',usecols=(0,1,2,4))
```