# StringIO example does not work

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, stringio

I try to understand how works *numpy.getfromtxt* method and *io.StringIO*.
On the officical website(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt) I found some examples. Here is one of them:

```
s = StringIO("1,1.3,abcde")
data = np.genfromtxt(s, dtype=[('myint','i8'),('myfloat','f8'),('mystring','S5')], delimiter=",")
```

But when I run this code on my computer I get: TypeError: must be str or None, not bytes

Tell me please how to fix it?

Comment: I can even write smth like this:
    s = StringIO("1,1.3,1.4")
    data = np.genfromtxt(s, delimiter=",")

and it will not work again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [200]: np.__version__
Out[200]: '1.14.0'
```

The example works for me:

```
In [201]: s = io.StringIO("1,1.3,abcde")
In [202]: np.genfromtxt(s, dtype=[('myint','i8'),('myfloat','f8'),
     ...: ... ('mystring','S5')], delimiter=",")
Out[202]: 
array((1, 1.3, b'abcde'),
      dtype=[('myint', '<i8'), ('myfloat', '<f8'), ('mystring', 'S5')])
```

It also works for a byte string:

```
In [204]: s = io.BytesIO(b"1,1.3,abcde")
In [205]: np.genfromtxt(s, dtype=[('myint','i8'),('myfloat','f8'),
     ...: ... ('mystring','S5')], delimiter=",")
Out[205]: 
array((1, 1.3, b'abcde'),
      dtype=[('myint', '<i8'), ('myfloat', '<f8'), ('mystring', 'S5')])
```

`genfromtxt` works with anything that feeds it lines, so I usually use a list of bytestrings directly (when testing questions):

```
In [206]: s = [b"1,1.3,abcde"]
In [207]: np.genfromtxt(s, dtype=[('myint','i8'),('myfloat','f8'),
     ...: ... ('mystring','S5')], delimiter=",")
Out[207]: 
array((1, 1.3, b'abcde'),
      dtype=[('myint', '<i8'), ('myfloat', '<f8'), ('mystring', 'S5')])
```

Or with several lines

```
In [208]: s = b"""1,1.3,abcde
     ...: 4,1.3,two""".splitlines()
In [209]: s
Out[209]: [b'1,1.3,abcde', b'4,1.3,two']
In [210]: np.genfromtxt(s, dtype=[('myint','i8'),('myfloat','f8'),
     ...: ... ('mystring','S5')], delimiter=",")
Out[210]: 
array([(1, 1.3, b'abcde'), (4, 1.3, b'two')],
      dtype=[('myint', '<i8'), ('myfloat', '<f8'), ('mystring', 'S5')])
```

---

It used to be that with `dtype=None`, `genfromtxt` created `S` strings.

[NumPy dtype issues in genfromtxt(), reads string in as bytestring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957667/numpy-dtype-issues-in-genfromtxt-reads-string-in-as-bytestring)

With 1.14, we can control the default string dtype:

```
In [219]: s = io.StringIO("1,1.3,abcde")
In [220]: np.genfromtxt(s, dtype=None, delimiter=",")
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Reading unicode strings without specifying the encoding argument is deprecated. Set the encoding, use None for the system default.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[220]: 
array((1, 1.3, b'abcde'),
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', 'S5')])
In [221]: s = io.StringIO("1,1.3,abcde")
In [222]: np.genfromtxt(s, dtype=None, delimiter=",",encoding=None)
Out[222]: 
array((1, 1.3, 'abcde'),
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<U5')])
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#encoding-argument-for-text-io-functions

Now I can generate examples with Py3 strings without producing all those ugly `b'string'` results (but got to remember that not everyone has upgraded to 1.14):

```
In [223]: s = """1,1.3,abcde
     ...: 4,1.3,two""".splitlines()
In [224]: np.genfromtxt(s, dtype=None, delimiter=",",encoding=None)
Out[224]: 
array([(1, 1.3, 'abcde'), (4, 1.3, 'two')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<U5')])
```

Comment: This is a recent change.  OP obviously has older version of numpy.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, now this question is clear for me.
The main problem was in the numpy version

Answer (score 1):

Consider upgrading numpy because for the current version of `numpy`, your code just works as written.  See [the mention in 1.14.0 release note highlights](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#highlights) and the section [Encoding argument for text IO functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#encoding-argument-for-text-io-functions) for the relevant changes in `np.genfromtxt`.

For older numpy, you use a string object for the input but the docs you linked say:

```
Note that generators must return byte strings in Python 3k.
```

So do what the docs say and give it a byte string:

```
import io
s = io.BytesIO(b"1,1.3,abcde")
```

Comment: I was a bit surprised that the `StringIO` worked, which is why I included the version number.  I had a vague memory that previously I had to use `BytesIO`.

Comment: It's all a bit confusing with the misnomer genfrom**txt** and the symbols in the dtype  'S5' vs 'U5'

Comment: Though the use of 'U5' vs 'S5' has nothing to do with the nature of the input string.  If given a filename `genfromtxt` opens the file in `rb` mode, and tries to work with bytestrings through out (for consistency with Py2 behavior).

Comment: Recently I was seeing the `VisibleDeprecationWarning`, but was ignoring it.  This is a welcomed upgrade.